# Sticky header with pure javascript, having problems with the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom, sticky

I'm having problems with a function to create a sticky header.

Code is like this:

```
function stick() {
var stickyNavTop = headerNav.offset().top;
var scrollTop = window.scrollTop();
while (stickyNavTop> scrollTop) {
    headerNav.className +=("sticky");
}
else {
    headerNav.className -= ("sticky")
}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6ApJ6/1/

CSS has a simple .sticky{position:fixed}

I believe the problem is in DOM but I don't know how to fix it. While I know jQuery could do this in a much easier fashion, the purpose of this is to learn JavaScript so I'm looking for answers in pure JS and not jQuery. Also any other problems I might have, please highlight them as they will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add a jsfiddle to of it please

Comment: I must say thats a very bad fiddle. Else with while

Comment: I have recently started learning JavaScript. I posted the question on the lookout for someone to help me with my problem. Please don't just make remarks of my bad fiddle without giving an alternative better option.

Comment: Yes buddy Will give you a solution.

Comment: And Also try to take some criticism from others. That will help you improve better as well

Comment: Sorry about that, thought you were just sayng that my fiddle was bad and leaving it there. My bad.

Comment: Did the below answer work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I have just made a new function call.

```
   var headerNav = document.getElementById("navbar");
     window.onscroll = function() {
     console.log('scrolled');
  var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;

  document.getElementById("navbar").style.top =scrollTop+"px";
  }
```

The this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6ApJ6/2/)

You can also set the style.position= "absolute"; in the javascript function.

Answer (score 1):

```
const header  = document.getElementById('**HEADER ID**');

addClassHeader = () => {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
}

removeClassHeader = () => {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    let getScrollposition = window.scrollY;
    if (getScrollposition > 0) {
        addClassHeader();
    } else {
        removeClassHeader();
    }
});
```